# UIImageView comparing images in game

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, image

I am working on a rock paper scissor shoe game, and I have no idea on how to do this. I have two UIImageView(s), and within each one is an image. I want to be able to compare the two images. I have looked up online, and cannot find anything. I want to be able to say

```
 if([imageView1.image == rock] && [imageView2.image == scissor]) {
    textLabel.text = @"You won!";
 }
```

I know that this syntax is wrong of course, but I am trying to show the english part of what I am looking for. Any help is appreciated.

I do not have any kind of source code to show you as I do not know what I am doing with this. I am not looking for pixel to pixel comparison, or anything complex, I am only looking for a way to determine if the image is the same or not.

Comment: Can you not tag the UIImageView with an integer depending on what image it has. so when you set imageView1 to rock, set imageView1.tag = 1;  2 for scissor, 3 for paper. then just compare the tag on the image view to know what it is. Better yet, create an enum for your types :)

Comment: Honestly, I have not even thought of that. That is SO much simpler, I have read to use a 3rd party API consisting of surveillance image comparisons and stuff like that. One more thing; I have never used enum much, just in Java, and haven't gotten to it yet, could you show me an example?

Comment: Of course, i'll leave it in an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

OK, Here is how I would solve this problem using enums. Firstly, declare your enum. You can call it whatever you like, i cam calling it RPS_STATE

```
enum RPS_STATE {
    RPS_ROCK,
    RPS_SCISSOR,
    RPS_PAPER,
    RPS_UNDEFINED
};
```

it's always useful to include an undefined state for init purposes. Now, these things defined in the enum are actually just integers from 0-3.

So you can use the following when you are setting your images.

```
 -(void) setToRock:(UIImageView *) view {
      view.image = rockImage;
      view.tag = RPS_ROCK;
 }

 -(void) setToScissor:(UIImageView *) view  {
      view.image = scissorImage;
      view.tag = RPS_SCISSOR;
 }

 -(void) setToPaper:(UIImageView *) view  {
      view.image = paperImage;
      view.tag = RPS_PAPER;
 }
```

then you can set and compare them nice and easy.

```
 [self setToPaper:imageView1];
 [self setToPaper:imageView2];

 if(imageView1.tag == imageView2.tag){

 }
```

and so on.  You can also use enums as a type. eg

```
 enum RPS_STATE variableHoldingOnlyRPSState;
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Wow, I cannot believe it is that simple! :) Thanks a lot! I'll edit the stuff I have, and see how it turns out. thanks again! GOd bless you